# Cognito Provider Returning 302 Error With Next-Auth

Tags: amazon-cognito, next.js13, next-auth

In my NextJs.13 applications I am using `next-auth` for authentication and am using a `Cognito` Provider. I have my provider setup here with accurate information.

```js
/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
    }),
  ],
  secret: 'secret',
};

const handler: NextAuthOptions = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

My issuer is the cognito domain followed by the user pool id as instructed ie. `https://cognito-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/user_pool_id`

I have my provider created in another file and imported in the `RootLayout` component as per their docs.

```js
/provider.tsx
'use client';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import React from 'react';

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

And my layout component

```js
/layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Now when I get to the signIn page after calling the signIn() method I am prompted with the Cognito button as so

[image]

But when I select the button it is showing me a 302 Error saying that it cannot find the cognito page

[image]

I'm not sure why the Hosted UI page isn't showing. I can confirm all the Cognito settings are correct as the UI is working in our previous application that was not using Next13 and AppRouter.

Here's the response header:

[image]

Comment: 'it cannot find the cognito page' - where does it say that? And for a `302`, the `Location` header will be key as it tells you where the redirect is going. Can you share the `Location` header for the 302 request?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I added the request headers

Comment: What callback URL have you defined in Cogntio? and are you sure you have all these variables in `env`? Your issuer can be the problem here - can you log and share the exact value?

Comment: I can verify that the app client id, app client secret are correct. I've tried three different issuers and all yield the same result. The first is the domain shown in the cognito console. The second was the domain shown in the cognito console followed by the user pool id (which should be the correct one) and the third was the one shown in next-auth https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{PoolId} with the correct information. All same result

Comment: I think I might know. I can see `csrf` which typically means you need HTTPS enabled. You’re running local host on HTTP - can you switch to HTTPS (self signed is fine) and then retry?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this @Ryne? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: @MattStannett Are you running on HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, I managed to fix it. By running it locally and finding the following error message "https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_parse_profile_error Profile id is missing in Okta OAuth profile response {error: {…}, OAuthProfile: {…}, message: 'Profile id is missing in Okta OAuth profile response'}". Previously this had worked, so it was a little weird that it stopped working suddenly. I added the missing "id" property inside the `profile` callback as per the NextJS OAuth [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider) (id: profile.sub,).